# How to get a corresponding unitary matrix from a tableau in stim?

Tags: stim

The following code

```
import stim
stim.Tableau.from_named_gate("CNOT").to_unitary_matrix(endian='big')
```

outputs

```
AttributeError: 'stim._stim_march_avx2.Tableau' object has no attribute 'to_unitary_matrix'
```

despite listed here https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Tableau.to_unitary_matrix

How to easily get the corresponding unitary matrix in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you linked is the api reference for the development version of stim (currently v1.9.dev1656756326). You probably have the latest stable version installed which would currently be v1.8. API references for specific versions such as 1.8 are kept on the [stim GitHub wiki](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki).

I'm intending to release 1.9 this week. In the mean time probably you'll just want to install the dev version (`pip install stim~=1.9.dev`).

(This is pretty funny to me by the way. That specific method had existed for all of 8 hours when this question was asked!)